# How to combine overflow:visible and overflow:scroll in CSS?

Tags: css, overflow, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on a page with horizontal scrolling and multiple columns. The first column of the text should be centered on the page and the other columns should be visible, too. Here is a sketch, which demonstrates what I have right now – an article with columns which is scrollable: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnTxg/1/). I would like to see the overflow text, too. I know `overflow-y:visible` and `overflow-y:scroll` cannot be combined, but how can achive something similar?

Only the text (article) should be scrollable, not the whole page.

Here are some images which illustrate what I would like to do:

[image: image 1 – starting position]
[image: image 2 – while scrolling]
[image: image 3 – scroll end position]

Comment: you cannot combine those two, one will trigger auto to the other one. Beside, you look for visible and scroll for the same direction , aren't you ?

Comment: I know, that I cannot combine these two, but I am looking for something which produces a similar result – scroll with visible overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure of what you are looking for, but here is a hint with display and text-indent:

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/uAidk)**

CSS to demonstrate idea :

```
.article-wrapper {
  border:solid;
  width:600px;
  margin:auto;
  text-indent:0;
  transition:1s
}
.article-wrapper:hover {
  text-indent:-500px;;
}
article {
  text-indent:0;
  display:inline-block;
  height:400px;
  width:500px;
  column-width:500px;
}
```

If this effect wanted, you may look for a way via transition, animation or javaScript to take control over it.

Comment: This will not work, because I have multiple (more than two) columns and the scrolling should be done manually. But the idea with text-indent is interesting.

Comment: @Pwdr If you combine pointer-events and bigger text-indent maybe this gives a bit more ideas : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KJEic , here what you can do (with image but can be columns) and a bit more efficient http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ActpB you need to retrieve width from javascript to set text-indent value or margin or translate , whatever is the technic you want to support

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your idea with `text-indent` led me to `padding` – this basically does what I want, the only problem is, that the last column cannot be scrolled to the starting position (the last image in first post), so `padding-right` seems not to be working there. [new jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LSHjQ/1/)

Comment: @Pwdr as i suggested you need to retrive width of element in order to get it's width and set the proper value to the negative text-indent (or margin...) . check this where scrollwidth  of ul is used and not width :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KJzLD notice the way to update/insert the rule .